"unparseable" vs. "unparsable"
What is the correct spelling of this word? See the discussion at (Codespell) false positive: unparseable.

Related: Is 'useable' preferred in certain regions, or just an alternate spelling of 'usable'?

parsable, unparsable, parsability
Per the OED, it’s parsable.
That’s because the rule in English spelling is that you drop the final ‑e before adding the suffix in such derivations. See also words like conversable, disbursable, endorsable, irreversible, submersible, traversable.
The exception to keep it applies only when it needs to remain in place to leave the sound represented by the preceding consonant unchanged, the way happens with words like chargeable, divorceable, enforceable, forgeable, pierceable, purgeable.
